# Why does my rye bread sink in the middle like this?

Tags: baking, bread, rye

My rye bread (made with a bread machine) usually sinks in the middle, like this one. It still tastes great, but I'd love to fix this problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/szW34.jpg

Here's my recipe:

1 ⅓  plus ⅛ cup warmish water

1 ½ cups white flour

1 ½ cups rye flour

1 tablespoon fennel

1 teaspoon salt

½ teaspoon yeast

I've switched between the regular setting and whole grain setting on the bread machine, it doesn't seem to make much difference.

EDIT: I'm using all purpose flour. And yes, I'm measuring the flour by cups. I feel like I'm pretty consistent with the measuring, though (I fluff it up and then measure) - do you think it might be too little or too much flour?

EDIT: The bread machine cycle I use takes 3 hours 40 minutes, so I don't think it's that. Other breads turn out fine in my bread machine (regular white bread, etc. Also, the only time I think the rye bread really turned out perfectly and rose properly, I had just ground the rye berries into flour myself. I don't have any more rye berries and am just using regular rye flour now.

EDIT: The linked question ([Why does my bread collapse in my bread machine?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2118/why-does-my-bread-collapse-in-my-bread-machine)) deals with regular wheat flour bread being **undercooked** and **doughy** in the bread machine. This question, while involving a bread machine, deals with **properly cooked** and **sagging** dough using rye flour which has a different composition and solution to the problem.

EDIT: I fixed the problem. Switched the yeast from 1/2 teaspoon to 1/4 teaspoon. That did the trick! It no longer rose a lot and sank, it just rose a reasonable amount. It comes out flat on the top, which is ok for me, and better than sunken.

Comment: Are you using bread flour or plain all-purpose white flour?

Comment: Are you really measuring the flour by volume? This is a notoriously inaccurate. Scales are much better.